# How has precipitation changed in Europe?

Tags: precipitation

I was just wondering if the precipitation in Europe has changed, for example, in its intensity or source? Has the source of the precipitation also changed? The water evaporates in the Atlantic. Is it possible that the polar amplification has caused it to evaporate further north?

Comment: Which time span are you interested in? Which research have you done?

Comment: I would take all time spans!

Comment: So, from this morning 9 AM to this morning 10 AM precipitation hasn't changed.

Comment: You got me, Ok I thought about all between 10 Years and since 1880